# how to fill a two dimensional array

Tags: python

I have a code that fills a two dimensional array using a special algorithm
When I run the code, on the line 'c[i][b] = d' for some reason the value of not only the iterable element changes, but also all the others, that is, if I change the value of the element c[0][1],
then the value in all elements will change: c[0][1], c[1][1], c[2][1] and so on
Why does this happen and how to fix it?

```
k = 8
colors = 3
main = 1

a = 0
default = 0
d = 0
c = [[0] * k] * n

for i in range(n):
    default += 1
    if default == colors + 1:
        default = 1
    a = default
    
    for b in range(k):
        d = a
        c[i][b] = d
        a += 1
        if a == colors + 1:
            a = 1 ``
```

Comment: This happens because of your initialization of c `c = [[0] * k] * n`

Comment: `c = [[0] * k] * n` This produces `n` identical references to the _same_ inner list.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = [[0] * k] * n
```

makes a list of `n` instances of a single `[0] * k` list.

You'll want

```
c = [[0] * k for _ in range(n)]
```

to have unique lists (since `[0] * k` will be evaluated separately for each iteration of `for _ in range(n)`).